# past vs past perfect tense

Tags: past-perfect

> A.This tree (be) *was* planted by the settlers who (found) ***founded***
> our city over four hundred years ago.

> B. This tree (be) *was* planted by the settlers who (found) ***had founded***
> our city over four hundred years ago.

According to a grammar website ,correct answer is A,"**founded**", but i think it should be "**had founded**" because first ,the city was found and then, the tree was planted. Am I wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *who founded our city* identifies that particular group of settlers, rather than saying anything about the  order in which things happened.

Compare:

> The tree was planted in 1620 by the settlers who had founded the city a year earlier.